# Ebean Query order by

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I want to get List from database order by column. I tried many ways, but no one returns the correct List. I tried with this:

```
List<models.Reserve> show = (List<models.Reserve>) new Model.Finder(String.class, models.Reserve.class).where().eq("shows_id", showId).orderBy("seat asc").findList();
```

and this

```
List<models.Reserve> show = (List<models.Reserve>) new Model.Finder(String.class, models.Reserve.class).where().eq("shows_id", showId).order("seat asc");
```

and this

```
List<models.Reserve> show = (List<models.Reserve>) new Model.Finder(String.class, models.Reserve.class).where().eq("shows_id", showId).orderBy("seat asc");
```

Comment: What about `orderBy().asc("seat")` ?

Comment: Not help  , return me the same result .

Comment: Can you show the code of your model?

Comment: do you have sql logs on